# OSE v3 connection timeout to maven repo while building maven project

Tags: maven, openshift

we are getting connection timeout error while building maven project.some can please help us on this issue.same project is working on osev2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you had this kind of problems, check out which repositories contains the requested artifact. In this case  as you can see in the link below, 3 repositories contains it. Add one of to your repositories/pluginRepositories section of your pom.xml.
Since this is a plugin you should add it as plugin repository.

```
   <pluginRepositories>
     ....
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>maven central</name>
          <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
```

Also 2.5 is a fairly old version, there is a newer 3.0.2 version (I would recommend changing it to this).

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5